# Firebase Email and password Authentication fails mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener((task)

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

This is my CustomerLoginRegisterActivity.java that gets customer's Email and password for login and registers email and password to firebase if they don't have an account,

i refered this tutorial : https://youtu.be/d8JMjBMQaMk?list=PLxefhmF0pcPl6gcWvrpTbjGO7rcMWY1jT

But The Firebase authentication fails everytime during registration.
I've enabled Sign-In method in my Firebase Account

```
 package com.example.saiadarsh.appendly;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class CustomerLoginRegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button CustomerLoginButton;
    private Button CustomerRegisterButton;
    private TextView CustomerRegisterLink;
    private TextView CustomerStatus;
    private EditText EmailCustomer;
    private EditText PasswordCustomer;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_login_register);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        CustomerLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.customer_login_btn);
        CustomerRegisterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.customer_register_btn);
        CustomerRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_customer_link);
        CustomerStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customer_status);
        EmailCustomer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_customer);
        PasswordCustomer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_customer);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);



        CustomerRegisterButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        CustomerRegisterButton.setEnabled(false);

        CustomerRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CustomerLoginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                CustomerRegisterLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                CustomerStatus.setText("Register Customer");

                CustomerRegisterButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                CustomerRegisterButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });



        CustomerRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                String email = EmailCustomer.getText().toString();
                String password = PasswordCustomer.getText().toString();

                RegisterCustomer(email, password);
            }
        });

        CustomerLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = EmailCustomer.getText().toString();
                String password = PasswordCustomer.getText().toString();

                SignInCustomer(email, password);
            }
        });
    }

    private void SignInCustomer(String email, String password)
    {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
        {
            Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginRegisterActivity.this, "Please write Email...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
        {
            Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginRegisterActivity.this, "Please write Password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {

            loadingBar.setTitle("Customer Login");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are on it");
            loadingBar.show();

            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                        {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginRegisterActivity.this, "Customer Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginRegisterActivity.this, "Login Unsuccessful, Please Try Again.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    private void RegisterCustomer(String email, String password)
    {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
        {
            Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginRegisterActivity.this, "Please write Email...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
        {
            Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginRegisterActivity.this, "Please write Password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {

            loadingBar.setTitle("Customer Registration");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are on it");
            loadingBar.show();

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                        {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginRegisterActivity.this, "Customer Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginRegisterActivity.this, "Registeration Unsuccessful, Please Try Again.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```